# Where are the review queue counters?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, review, top-bar

The review queue counters have disappeared:

> [image: no count]

Where are they?

When I did screenshot the Close Votes queue was not empty, if someone think so.

Comment: They are removed and replaced with dots to indicate which queue needs attention. At least that is how it works now on SO, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355446/top-bar-review-queue-pending-count-vanished

Comment: @rene ok! Where are our dots? :)

Comment: The queue is empty, you can count on me ...

Comment: must be white dots ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the review queues are empty, then this would be the expected behavior in the new design. There is a minor bug that the space for the grey/red indicators is not being preserved so the layout subtly changes.

The absence of counts is also part of the design. You can still get to the counts via the "all queues" link.

Comment: So, dots are here but no visible yet due to a bug, right?

Comment: I think this is actually a bit more broken than that. I'm seeing a red indicator that there *are* reviews to do but when I click on the dropdown, there are no red dots.

Comment: @Catija probably items you can't review yourself e.g. something you voted to close outside review. This was the case in the old top bar as well, where the count was usually off. :/

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Nope. The items are completely reviewable... I reviewed them after noticing this problem. Orange/red alert popped up, no dots, click to the "all queues" and I've got two items in one queue and one in a second queue.

Comment: @Catija So might be worthy of a separate bug report. Joe what you think?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Well, there already **is** one [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301520/review-queues-in-the-dropdown-menu-have-no-indicator-even-when-theres-reviews)... it was just closed as a duplicate of this.

Comment: @Catija wrongly closed IMO, voted to reopen.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I have the same behaviour on health. No counts, no red dots, lots to review.

Comment: @JohnP yeah 22 close votes, 20 first post reviews... hmm.... so it's probably just borked on all sites except SO

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd If it was working fine on MSE, I'd be chalking it up to an error in the mod-only part of the roll-out but it's not working here, though there aren't a ton of review items at the moment.

Comment: Our main dev for this feature is currently in a different part of the world, so I'm trying to find someone to investigate.

Comment: Adam appears to be online.

Comment: Thanks for checking this out @Joe.

Comment: We are making a change to turn on the right site setting to address this. Please let me know if you see any problems. You should start seeing grey/red dots now.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Are you spying on me? ;)

Comment: @AdamLear just keeping an open eye... ;)